Meaning of 「なんといったって」
I found this example sentence in Shinkanzen Master Choukai N1 (p 23):

冬はなんといったってスキーがいいよ。(= 何よりも)

I’m guessing it means:
When it comes to winter, skiing is the best.
I tried to identify the individual parts / find some similar grammar points:

なん = 何
N といった = such as N; like N
って = という; quotation marker; topic marker
Verb［た］って = Even if, Even though, No matter how
何と言っても = no doubt; 'no matter what is said, (A)'

I tried to literally translate it:
As for winter, even if you said something such as “anything”, skiing is good.
As in:
During the winter, no matter what (other sports) you might mention, skiing is the best among them.
Is that the correct interpretation?
Or is it the other way around:
Even if you listed any other options (spring, summer, autumn) winter is the best (because) skiing is great.

This phrase has nothing to do with といった meaning "such as". Parse it like this:

なん: what
と: quotative particle
言ったって = 言っても: even though one says

Thus, the combined literal meaning is "even though one says what(ever)" or "no matter what one/you/people might say". However, since this is a fixed phrase, it's often better to translate it like "After all", etc.
